# What does “linear forms” mean in this context?

Tags: heraldry, terminology

> Spanish heraldry is chiefly remarkable for the manner in which the different bearings are connected in the shield, and for the frequent divisions of it "per saltire"; while Italian heraldry is simpler in its ***linear forms***, though the objects and devices it employs more nearly resemble those of German than of English blazonry. (Jenkins, Robert C., Heraldry: English and Foreign, pVI)

Jenkins describes about marshalling of arms in Spanish heraldry and then explains the simplicity of "linear forms" in Italian heraldry. Hence, is it possible his intent alludes to a genealogical concept? In other words, is it possible his intent from "linear forms" does not refer to the ordinaries, but refers to the simpler forms of "divisions of the field"?

In other words:

1. In Spanish heraldry there are a lot of instances with quartering.
2. In Italian heraldry but there are a lot of simple coat of arms with no quartering.
3. because quartering in heraldry has firm relations with genealogical matters, so, there is a probability that Jenkins wants by use of "linear forms" also refers to the genealogical, and not only the heraldic, aspect of subject. (heraldic aspect of subject refers to the category of charges.)

Comment: Are you confusing the word "linear" with "lineal"?

Comment: Certainly not. I think it is possible that Jenkins wants to make a delicate connection between heraldic forms and genealogical matters. And maybe I am thinking in a wrong way...

Comment: This is no better a question than when you asked it at http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/153960/what-does-mean-linear-forms-in-this-context (where it was closed with some useful comments). IMO, the term 'linear forms' is being used in a literal sense to describe the visual elements in use in Italian heraldry rather than some abstruse genealogical concept. ( A simple google for 'heraldry' and 'linear forms' doesn't throw up anything except references to visual elements).

Comment: I have asked this one here again because when I asked that one in there, I did not know there is also a "stackexchange" what devotes to genealogy.

Comment: Would you be able to edit your Question to include more details about the precise genealogical problem that you are trying to solve, please?  For example, which two (or more) individuals are you seeking to determine a genealogical relationship between, and what other evidence do you have supporting that?